# Toggle EditorGUI.Foldout programmatically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor

For Unity3D editor scripts, is it possible to set `EditorGUI.Foldouts` to closed or opened state programmatically? I would like the relevant foldouts for my script initially opened when a user selects the game object the first time.

Likewise I'd like to close several foldouts by default so they don't take up space in the component pane, for example the foldout of a `RectTransform` and a `RawImage` which are added dynamically when the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

EditorGUI.Foldout second parameter is bool

You could set that bool to open or close as you see fit. You don't need to use the same bool that return from it. Or you can modified the value of it before or after that line

Such as

```
bool fold;

fold = SomeLogicFunction();
EditorGUI.Foldout(rect,fold,"Folder");
```

or

```
bool fold;

fold = EditorGUI.Foldout(rect,fold,"Folder");
fold = fold && SomeLogicFunction();
```

or

```
string name = "none";
if(selectedGameObject != null)
    name = selectedGameObject.name;
EditorGUI.Foldout(rect,selectedGameObject != null,name);
```

FYI. FoldOut is actually just toggle the arrow of that line. You are the person to decide that when it return true, what will you draw below it